# I'd like to write a query statement for this problem

Tags: sql, mysql

I would like to write a query statement that returns the names and majors of students whose credits for all subjects are A.

This is the query I've created, but it doesn't work as intended. Could you tell me how?

```
SELECT Name, Major
FROM STUDENT S , GRADE_REPORT G
WHERE S.Student_number = G.Student_number AND
      G.Grade = ALL  (SELECT GRADE
              FROM GRADE_REPORT
                          WHERE GRADE = 'A');
```

Table `STUDENT`:

| Name | Student_number | Class | Major |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Smith | 17 | 1 | CS |
| Brown | 8 | 2 | CS |

Table `GRADE_REPORT`:

| Student_number | Section_identifier | Grade |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 17 | 112 | B |
| 17 | 119 | C |
| 8 | 85 | A |
| 8 | 92 | A |
| 8 | 102 | B |
| 8 | 135 | A |

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read and maintain, and easier to convert to outer join if needed!

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as properly formatted text (no images, no links.)

Comment: What is the intended result and what result are you getting?

Comment: *students whose credits for all subjects are A* Solve the task read from backward side: students who have no credits other than A. PS. Does the student who have no matched rows in GRADE_REPORT at all matches this condition?

Comment: Under the current conditions, there will be no return of tuples because no student has an A grade for all subjects.

I wonder what kind of query I should write to check if all grades are A.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This first query will also return students who have no grades at all:

```
SELECT s.Name, s.Major
FROM STUDENT s
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM GRADE_REPORT
    WHERE Student_number = s.Student_number
    AND Grade > 'A'
);
```

This query will only return students who have all As:

```
SELECT s.Name, s.Major
FROM STUDENT s
JOIN GRADE_REPORT g ON s.Student_number = g.Student_number
GROUP BY s.Student_number
HAVING MAX(g.Grade) = 'A';
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. With all due respect, may I also know how to fill out a query that returns students who have not received an A grade in all subjects?

Comment: @DongHaSHIN `... AND Grade = 'A' );` and `.. MIN(g.Grade) > 'A';`